# Headphone microphone not being recognized ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, audio, microphone

My laptop is an MSI GV-62 8RD-200. It has two audio jacks available (one headphone and one microphone). However, when I try to use the microphone, it only uses the internal microphone. In the Settings, the only microphone available is the internal microphone.

What should I do to use the microphone found on my earphone?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here some issue but finally fixed after i've connected the mic to external power source and reinstall the OS as shown here [Image Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fJir.png) don't forget to open you Pc cover and cut the main power cable

Comment: ahahha WTF https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fJir.png ??